# ORA-12505 while creating new connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed few moments later the Oracle database XE 18.4.0.0.0 (18c).
Next I downloaded the Oracle SQL Developer tool and I tried to create a new connection, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

The master password is correct and the listerner is running, (UPDATED after @EdStevens reply):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 22-OTT-2020 09:04:27

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Avvio di tnslsnr: attendere...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Il file dei parametri di sistema Þ C:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Ascolto su: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Connessione a (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
STATO del LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Versione                  TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Data di inizio            22-OTT-2020 09:04:34
Tempo di attivitÓ           0 giorni 0 ore 0 min. 12 sec.
Livello trace             off
Sicurezza                 ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
File di parametri listenerC:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Summary table degli endpoint di ascolto...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Summary table dei servizi...
Il servizio "CLRExtProc" ha 1 istanze.
  L'istanza "CLRExtProc", stato UNKNOWN, ha 1 handler per questo servizio...
Il servizio "database" ha 1 istanze.
  L'istanza "XE", stato UNKNOWN, ha 1 handler per questo servizio...
Il comando Þ stato eseguito
```

Here my `listener.ora`:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PortatileGabriele)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

And `tnsnames.ora`:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\gabri\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I hope that someone can help me!

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %ORACLE_HOMEd%
%ORACLE_HOMEd%

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %ORACLE_SID%
%ORACLE_SID%

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba'

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Gio Ott 22 14:27:19 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS: errore dell'adattatore del protocollo


Immettere il nome utente: SYSTEM
Immettere la password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS: errore dell'adattatore del protocollo


Immettere il nome utente:
```

Comment: Which error is "this error"?

Comment: I attached the image and I inserted the link. I don't have enough reputation to add directly in the post. If you look at the 3rd line there is a link "Screenshot of the error I get"

Comment: Thanks @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: Right, it is now visible :) As of the error: you used SID = XE; shouldn't you use **CLRExtProc** instead?

Comment: Already done, but I'm getting ```Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection``` @Littlefoot

Comment: for 18c, you can't use SID anymore, you need to use service, also your listener config should look more like https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/connecting-oracle-database-xe.html

Comment: I'm completely new to oracle db. I need to install it for a university course and they provide us a very small tutorial with no mention to this problems. So what i need to do @thatjeffsmith?

Answer (score 1):

First, the error 'listener does not know of sid' is absolutley correct.  We see from 'lsnrctl status' that no *database* is registered with the listener.  So until you get a database actually started and registered with the listener, nothing else matters.

Second, once you do get a database running, your SQL Dev 'connection type' of 'basic' means you are supplying all necessary connection info directly, and tnsnames.ora is not called into play.  NOthing wrong with that, but if you *do* want to use tnsnames, then change your connection type to 'tns'.  The necessary input fields with change accordingly.

Third, as mentioned, whether you use tns or basic connection, you want to specify service name, not sid.

Comment: Thanks. I've found a way to add a database to the listener. I updated the listener status in the post. Now I'm getting this error: `Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection`. Already tried to change to localhost from 127.0.0.1 both. Added also this line in `listener.ora` which i found in some other question: `DIAG_ADR_ENABLED_LISTENER = OFF
DIRECT_HANDOFF_TTC_LISTENER=OFF`

Comment: What, _exactly_, did you do to "add a database to the listener"?  From you updated output of lsnrctl, I'd guess you added a SID_LIST entry in listener.ora.  But that does not address the database not being _started_.  Messing around with HOST is not the issue. That affects network routing from client to listener, and we know by the nature of the errors that  the requests are reaching the listener.

Comment: Open a command prompt and enter the following:  'echo %ORACLE_HOMEd%',   'echo %ORACLE_SID%',  'sqlplus / as sysdba'. Copy the text of the entire session and paste into your opening post.  No screen shots, copy the text and paste it. If you don't know how to copy text from a command window, look it up.

Comment: Added output at the end of the post @EdStevens

Comment: Echoing ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID should have returned actual values.  Enter your 'services' control panel (from a command prompt, 'services.msc').  Scroll down the list of services and find anything starting with 'Oracle'. THere should be a service 'OracleServiceXE'. And it should have a status of 'Running'.  Please confirm.

Comment: I've got only to services related to Oracle: `OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener` and `OracleOraDB18Home1MTSRecoveryService`

Comment: Then you don't have a database at all.  Since this is a homework issue, I'd strongly suggest you work with your instructor.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! In the meanwhile I tried to install it on Ubuntu on a VM and it's working there

Comment: Ubuntu is an entirely different branch of the linux family tree than the one for which oracle was designed.  Attempts to get it working on ubuntu are always hacks and even with initial success, you will never know if new problems are the result of running there.  If you are going to create a vm with a linux for this, then you should use oracle's own 'oracle linux'.

Comment: Thank you so much, very precious comment for me